# jlrs: Creating julia array in Rust and using it as an argument to julia function

Tags: rust, julia

im using jlrs crate to using julia functions from rust code. Now I want to use julia function that takes of array of strings as an argument. Here is the function that I want to call:

```
    function create_temporals(ts::Vector{String}, ts_format="yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSzzzz")
    ....
end
```

Here is the rust code. Problem is that I don't know how to convert rust data to julia array. I have tried to use jlrs::data::managed::Array but it wants ExtendedTarget as an argument and I don't know how to do that. Also how do I give rust data to the julia array?

```
pub fn _call1<'target, 'data, T: Target<'target>>(
    target: T, 
    module: &str, 
    function: &str, 
    data1: Value<'_, 'data>
) -> JlrsResult<ValueResult<'target, 'data, T>> {
    unsafe {
        let res = Module::main(&target)
            .submodule(&target, module)?
            .as_managed()
            .function(&target, function)?
            .as_managed()
            //geneerinen call on olemassa myös
            .call1(target, data1);

        Ok(res)
    }
}
```

```
pub fn _temporals<T>(timestamps: &T) {
    let mut frame = StackFrame::new(); 
    let mut pending = unsafe { RuntimeBuilder::new().start().expect("Could not init Julia") };
    let mut julia = pending.instance(&mut frame);

    // Include some custom code defined in MyModule.jl.
    // This is safe because the included code doesn't do any strange things.

    unsafe {
        let path = PathBuf::from("structures.jl");
        if path.exists() {
            julia.include(path).expect("Could not include file");
        } else {
            julia
                .include("src/Predicer/src/structures.jl")
                .expect("Could not include file");
        }
    }

    // An extended target provides a target for the result we want to return and a frame for
    // temporary data.
    let _x = julia.scope(|mut frame| {
        
        let timestamps: Vec<String> = vec![
        "2023-06-20T10:30:00".to_string(),
        "2023-06-20T10:45:00".to_string(),
        "2023-06-20T11:00:00".to_string(),
    ];

    // Convert the Rust vector into a Julia array
    let temporals = Array::new(&mut frame, (3,));

        let module = "Structures"; 
        let function = "create_temporals"; 
        let _result_node = _call1(frame, module, function, temporals);
        Ok(()) 
        
    }).expect("result is an error");

}
```

Comment: Both Rust and Julia have provisions for sending and receiving C strings via the Cstring type in each language. You could use a Cstring as the passed intermediary type. Care would be needed in handling the memory Rust allocates -- Julia should not garbage collect such memory.

Comment: So should I change the data type of the Julia function? I have a pretty big threshold to change the Julia data structures, because I want to make an interface to one ready-made tool, and changing the data structures in Julia would probably be quite a big job.